# ¿En dónde guardar el valor de descuento?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo una funcionalidad en donde puedo aplicar descuentos por proveedor, editorial o producto. Dicho descuento se ve reflejado cuando el usuario ingresa a la web, esto lo hago usando los accesores en laravel.

```php
public function getProductDiscountPriceAttribute()
    {

        $calc_discount = new CalculatorDiscountValue();
        // Search discount to apply
        $discount = $this->discount_coordinator->getDiscount($this);
        // calc it discount price
        return $calc_discount->calculate($discount, $this->product_value);
    }
```

Eso funciona perfectamente y me trae todos los descuentos por cualquier modelo

[image: discunt apply it]

EL problema de dicha funcionalidad es que si un usuario desea aplicar un ordenación por menor precio, el sistema no tendría en cuenta el valor de descuento, puesto que no existe un registro de dicho valor; en dicho caso habría una inconsistencia a nivel de usuario. Entonces me surge una pregunta ¿Qué debo hacer? ¿Calcular el descuento cuando el administrador lo este aplicando? Tendría la ventaja de poder realizar una ordenación por precio_descuento, pero la complejidad de calcular dichos descuentos por lotes grandes de productos; o ¿habría alguna otra mejor opción? ¿Qué me aconsejan hacer? Gracias por su tiempo.

Base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para obtener el menor precio

```php
public function getProductsByDiscount($search): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        return Product::lower($search)->with($this->getRelations())->paginate(52);
    }
```

```php
public function scopeLower($query, $search)
    {
        if ($search) {
            return $query->orderBy('product_value', $search);
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: El código va como texto

Comment: En que momento ordenas los productos por precio?

Comment: @porloscerros he actualizado la publicación. Lo obtengo antes de realizar la paginacion. Como puedes observar apunto al precio del producto porque no tengo guardado el valor de descuento.

Comment: No tendrías por que almacenar los precios con descuentos sino solamente ordenar los precios modificados ya sea en el backend o desde la vista

Comment: @BetaM ¿Pero no sería costoso ordenarlos? Porque si hay 10 mil deberé ordenarlos todos y luego devolverlos ordenados. O tal vez no entendí.

Comment: No soy muy bueno con mysql, pero podrías probar con algo así: `->orderByRaw('(product_value * discount_percentag / 100) desc')`. O también haciendo el cálculo y asignado el resultado a un alias tipo: `->selectRaw('(product_value * discount_percentag / 100) as discounted_price' )->orderBy('dicounted_price', 'asc')`

Comment: qué contiene el `$search` que le pasas al scope?

Comment: Le paso el precio de forma ascendente o descendente si el usuario lo selecciona. En estos momentos estoy en proceso de depuración de código. la respuesta que da @porloscerrosΨ es muy buena, pero lo evaluaré más adelante; en una próxima actualización. Mientras tanto dejaré abierta la publicación.

Comment: @ffflabs he dado mi respuesta a tu pregunta, pido disculpas por no haberte etiquetado anteriormente.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ he dado la solución al problema que planteé aquí. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, fue de mucha utilidad. Al final del post dí la respuesta por sql. Me demoré un poco, por algunos problemas presentados por el COVID.

Comment: Perdón por la ignorancia. ¿Cuál es la sección de respuestas? @porloscerrosΨ espero ingresar al pc y corregir eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue la siguiente. Dejo la respuesta en formato sql. ¿Qué hace el código?
La función coalesce verificará cada opción, con esto podemos determinar si un producto posee o no descuento; luego, lo asignamos a la variable productWithDiscount. Si un producto no posee ningún descuento asignamos el mismo valor del producto en almacén.

```sql
SELECT products.id, products.product_code, 
products.product_name, 
products.product_value, 
makers.maker_name,
COALESCE((SELECT products.product_value-(products.product_value*(discounts.discount_value/100)) FROM discountables JOIN discounts ON discountables.discount_id=discounts.id WHERE products.id = discountables.discountable_id AND discountables.discountable_type IN ('App\\Models\\Product') AND discounts.discount_type='generic'),
         (SELECT products.product_value-(products.product_value*(discounts.discount_value/100)) FROM discountables JOIN discounts ON discountables.discount_id=discounts.id WHERE makers.id = discountables.discountable_id AND discountables.discountable_type IN ('App\\Models\\Maker') AND discounts.discount_type='generic'),
        (SELECT products.product_value-(products.product_value*(discounts.discount_value/100)) FROM discountables JOIN discounts ON discountables.discount_id=discounts.id WHERE providers.id = discountables.discountable_id AND discountables.discountable_type IN ('App\\Models\\Provider') AND discounts.discount_type='generic'), products.product_value) totalWithDiscount

FROM products

LEFT JOIN makers ON products.maker_id = makers.id
LEFT JOIN providers ON makers.provider_id = providers.id

ORDER BY totalWithDiscount
LIMIT 30
```

Agradezco a @porloscerros por darme la idea y así encontrar esta primera solución. Habría que evaluar si es o no eficiente; ya que hace uso de tres sub consultas.

Comment: Pero por que no haces el orden por precio directamente en el frontend??